# Finding the index of &quot; in a string

Tags: php, quotes, strpos

I've been having a (hopefully stupid) issue, and I was wondering if anyone could help.

I'm trying to determine if a string begins with `&quot;`, i.e.:

```
&quot;-------- Original Message
```

I've tried everything--`strpos($str, '"') === 0`, `strpos(html_entity_decode($str), '"') === 0`, but, no matter what, I'm always finding that `strpos(***, '"')` is false--not 0.

There's more context here (parsing csv rows from a webform, trying to find where a quoted message begins), but I'm coming up empty handed.

I'm using php 7. Coming from a JS/TS background, so some of these nuances might just be going over my head.

Does anyone have any intuition as to what might be going on? I can provide code/more context if need-be. Tried staring this down for a few hours last night, but no dice.

Comment: Maybe try: `strpos($str, '&quot;') === 0` ?

Comment: Just gave that a whir. It's working in sandbox, but not on my server, which is weirding me out.

Comment: Can also try: `mb_strpos($str, '&quot;') === 0` to see if this makes any difference?

Comment: Hm. Works with the raw string ('&quot;-------- Original Message'). This might just be some other issue in how I'm iterating over the rows of the csv/parsing rows, versus a character issue. :(

I might have just hyperfixated on the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this can help... function htmlspecialchars_decode converts &quot; into a quotation mark

```
<?php
$str = "&quot;--------";
echo "Position is: ";
echo strpos(htmlspecialchars_decode($str), '"'); 
echo "\n";
echo "Is quotation mark at the beginning?";
echo strpos(htmlspecialchars_decode($str), '"')==0; 
echo "\n"; 
?>
```

Output:

```
Position is: 0
Is quotation mark at the beginning? 1
```

Comment: Man, my lack of php knowledge is shining through! Using this higher up in my code managed to fix everything. The input for the above is coming through a POST request, so something wacky must have been going on.